# How to comfortably carry a pen drive in any attire without risk of physical damage?

Tags: comfort, stationery, safety, bicycle

I often find pen drive necessary with me at all times. However, I'm having trouble finding an appropriate way to carry it with me.

Earlier, I used to keep it in my wallet. But carrying the wallet in my pant pocket placed some pressure on the pen drive, because of which it's getting damaged. I lost two pen drives because of some hardware failure as a result of this.

Currently, I'm using an ID tag to wear the pen drive around my neck. It's fine if I'm going to office, as I'll be wearing a shirt. So, the pen drive won't have to dangle in front of me. I don't like that. However, that's the problem when I'm not wearing formals (when I'm at home or at friend's place).

In such situations, I do have the option of carrying it in my short's (or pant's) pocket. But when I have to ride a bicycle or a motorcycle, it's not so comfortable as I have to keep checking if it's still safe in my pocket.

So, is there a way I could carry the pen drive both in my formal as well as informal attire, that's also comfortable?

**Edit:**

This is my pen drive.

[image: Pen drive]

Comment: You can put the pentdrive in the rigth little pocket of your jean.

Comment: The OP mentioned this in the question, and why it wouldn't do.

Answer (score 5):

Many flash sticks / pen drives nowadays have keyring loops.
I simply carry a flash stick on my keyring - like this...

[image: Flash stick on keyring]

As my keys are always in my pocket if I'm outside the house, the flash stick is always with me.
Everybody has a pocket in which they keep keys in a comfortable manner.

Comment: Everybody? My wife frequently laments the lack of pockets in her dresses.

Comment: @chepner Purse/bag/backpack/fanny pack?  She must keep her keys somewhere...

Comment: I bought one just for this purpose, slightly different style than the image here.  It's a solid metal encasing with the connector inside the tip instead of protruding from a separate encasing like the OP's (which is susceptible to damage from bending due to pressure in a pocket).

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned riding a bicycle or motorcycle, might I suggest this solution:

[image] [image] [image]

**Search: [Running belt](https://www.google.com/search?q=running+belt&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X)**

This is a lean **running waistpack** — essentially it's a long, zippered neoprene pouch which wraps around you beltline to be worn over or under your shirt when you have small items which are easily lost when you are active.

It's very comfortable to be worn all day. It's zippered, so you don't have to keep checking if your stuff is still safe in your pocket. And it's very stealthy, so it doesn't look like a "fanny pack" or anything of *that* design. You can store *any* small items like keys, money, the cards we carry around, and it typically stretches big enough to hold phones, wallets, etc… if you need that.

Answer (score 3):

A retractable badge holder would probably do the trick.  You could wear it on your belt, and instead of attaching a badge, you could attach your USB drive.

[image]

Note that the cord attached to it can easily extend and retract.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a prosthetic fashioned to house the USB drive, such as [this individual](https://www.cnet.com/news/usb-prosthetic-finger-gives-new-meaning-to-thumbdrives/) whose missing digit has been replaced with a literal "thumb drive."

Comment: Finally, somebody who could give MS Windows the finger!

Comment: Interesting, but not widely applicable :)

Comment: ... so he should cut a finger off, to enable this convenience?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Think of it as an implant in reverse

Answer (score 1):

If you have a coin pocket in your pants that you're not keeping coins in, that's a good solution because the flash drive usually fits snugly and is unlikely to fall out. This depends on the type of pants, of course, but biking shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also known as a "fob pocket" or "watch pocket" or "change pocket" in different areas.

Answer (score 0):

This slightly dodges the question at hand. But my advice is to ditch the thumb drive completely. Cloud storage is automatically everywhere you go that has an internet connection and the free tier from most companies is often larger in storage than the average thumb drive.

I use Google Drive and their client program means the files are automatically downloaded to my personal PC while the website means I can still access the files at work, on my phone, a friends house, or anywhere else.

This will never break or corrupt (through your own fault) and the Google one (maybe others) even has it's own recycle bin so deleted files can be recovered from wherever no matter where they're deleted.

And you never have to carry anything anywhere - all it takes is an email and password. (I also use 2FA for extra security).

Comment: Cloud storage is great in lots of ways, but it's not even remotely a substitute for a local flash drive. Try booting a laptop with a dead hard drive from your Dropbox account.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself one of these [https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233806&cm_re=CORSAIR_SURVIVOR-*-20-233-806-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233806&cm_re=CORSAIR_SURVIVOR-_-20-233-806-_-Product) Ive had one for years (since 4GB was considered big....) and its survived through everything Ive put it through.

Answer (score 0):

I especially enjoy keeping this on me with Kali linux and some other misc. tools. =)

[image: credit card usb]